# Channel ID different in MS Teams iOS Mobile App different from ID in MS Teams desktop client

Tags: single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

We've built a Custom Tab for Microsoft Teams and use the context (TeamId, ChannelId) to show corresponding information on that tab.

Since a month or two this no longer works for the (iOS) mobile App for Microsoft Teams. Investigating the issue it turns out the ChannelId that Microsoft Teams is publishing in the context, differs between MS Teams Desktop App and MS Teams Mobile App. More precise: no matter what channel you are opening in the iOS MS Teams App the ChannelId of the General channel (which equals TeamId) is passed in the context as ChannelId (instead on the ChannelId at hand).

Please note: in the past our Custom App has worked perfectly in both Apps, so something changed in the MS Teams Mobile App. To me it seems really odd that the ChannelId published in Mobile App is different from the one published in Desktop Client (and Graph API).

How can we come to an ChannelId that is the same across all Apps on all platforms?